# Turn off snap-to in Google Drawings

Tags: google-drawings

How do I turn off "snap-to" in Google Drawings?

I have a ton of shapes with snapped lines to other shapes, and every time I need to rearrange shapes or drag a line elsewhere or want a line to end at a specific location, its large radius for snapping causes unwanted behavior.

[image]

Comment: try pressing ctrl or shift or both

Comment: @user0 Awesome! thanks so much

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This type of action is generally performed with pressing of **<kbd>`SHIFT`</kbd>** key or **<kbd>`CTRL`</kbd>** or both 
**<kbd>`CTRL`</kbd>** + **<kbd>`SHIFT`</kbd>** across most major platforms where snapping needs to be cased in order to finetune the position of an object.

Comment: That doesn't appear to work in a gdoc Drawing. I've tried every combination, and my arrow still wants to snap to a pre-defined location on a circle.

Comment: cmd + shift on Mac

Answer (score 7):

Hold down the **<kbd>`ALT`</kbd>** key while dragging the line to avoid the snap points

Comment: This is the only solution that works. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

In view -> snap to, the values can either be grid, guides or null. Clicking on a 'ticked' value will untick it to null and allow movement to any position with no snapping.

Comment: Where is the "view -> snap" option located?

Answer (score 0):

In Drawing, click on "Actions" and scroll down to "Snap to (X)". Then, click off the pre-selected "Guides". Tadaaa! Should work.

Answer (score 0):

An easy way, but not perfect way, is to just put it as close as possible to where you want it and use the arrow keys on a computer.

Answer (score 0):

On the menu bar:
View > Snap to > Uncheck both "Grid" and "Guides"